# Latex table with wrapped text in cells

Tags: latex

The text in the second column is displaying in the first column. I can't work out why? Any suggestions?

[image: latex table with error]

```
\begin{table*} 
\begin{tabular}{|p{8cm}|p{8cm}|} 
\hline \textbf{Heading 1}\\\\Text \\ 
& \textbf{Heading 2}\\ Text \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table*}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Latex tables are formatted horizontally: `&` separates cells/columns, `\\` indicates the end of a row of cells.
Specify row one as

```
A & B \\
```

row two as

```
C & D \\
```

So your case should be encoded:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*} 
\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|} 
\hline \textbf{Heading 1} & \textbf{Heading 2}\\
  Text col 1 with plenty of extra text
  &Text col 2 with plenty of extra text\\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(I have reduced the width of the cells for display purposes.)

If you want a newline in a given cell, just leave a blank line in the input file.  Here are two different ways with your text.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*} 
\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|} 
\hline \textbf{Heading 1} & \textbf{Heading 2}\\
  Text col 1 with plenty of extra text.

  And more lines of text in column one.

  Yet more lines.
  &Text col 2 with plenty of extra text.\\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table*}

\begin{table*} 
\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|} 
\hline \textbf{Heading 1} 

  Text col 1 with plenty of extra text.

  And more lines of text in column one.

  Yet more lines.
  &\textbf{Heading 2} 

    Text col 2 with plenty of extra text.\\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Both tables now produce:
[image: Sample output with more lines]

Comment: thanks but it does not work as it is creating a new row. I have a few newlines of text in each cell. I tried making separate rows but when 1 line is long it wraps affecting the other cell.

Comment: @orbital I have updated my code showing how to deal with multiline text.  The `&` and `\\` separate the cells.

Comment: With multiple lines this leave a blank space \begin{table*} 
\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|} 
\hline \textbf{Heading 1} & \textbf{Heading 2}\\
  Text col 1 with plenty of extra text
  &Text col 2 with plenty of extra text\\ 
    Text col 1 small
  &Text col 2 with plenty of extra text\\ 
    Text col 1 with plenty of extra text
  &Text col 2 with plenty of extra text\\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table*}

Comment: \\  starts a new line of cells, you are looking for a newline within a cell, see my updated answer.